# Same class with different extends

Tags: java, android

I have a two classes with the same content, but first class is for android version `<honeycomb` and extends support library for fragments. 
Second class for version higher than `honeycomb` and extends native sdk library. Is it possible to have only one class file but somehow extend it for both?

Comment: No, you can't. I will recommend using composition over inheritance, and pass the class that implements the real method from the specific version rather than trying to extend from 2 or more classes.

Comment: Use ActionBarSherlock, or *always* use the support library.

Comment: @323go i would like to use support lib, but it does not have preference fragment in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, but both of them can implement the same Interface, and the class that wants to use these 2 classes will just have to use that interface (This is called the `Strategy` Pattern). Depending on the version of the OS, you'll return a class or the other when asking for that interface (`Factory` Pattern).